# Google Maps API v2 and static text

Tags: android, google-maps

The new Android Google Maps API allows easier polygons, polylines, etc. However, I also want to add static text to the map.

Is this possible, or should I add a custom view?

Comment: where do you want to show static text?

Comment: To the screen, without the text to be rotated or scaled.

Comment: why not use a textview above the map fragment and display it on  screen